# Dismiss the nested stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

In my react-native project I am using libraries

```js
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
```

I have nested navigator, like this:

```js
// root level I have a stack navigator where it contains two screens, `Home` and `Settings`.
const App = ()=> {
  const rootStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <rootStack.Navigator>
        <rootStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <rootStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </rootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

// The Settings screen is a nested stack navigator
const Settings = ()=> {
  const settingsStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <settingsStack.Navigator>
      <settingsStack.Screen name="SettingsOne" component={SettingsOneScreen} />
      <settingsStack.Screen name="SettingsTwo" component={SettingsTwoScreen} />
    </settingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

As you can see, the Settings screen is actually another level (nested) stack navigator.

On `SettingsOneScreen`, there is a button navigates user to `SettingsTwoScreen`.

```js
const SettingsOneScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   ...
   return (
      ...
      <Button onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("SettingsTwo")}/>
   )
}
```

Now, on `SettingsTwoScreen`, I have a button, I would like to close the whole settings navigator stack when user tap on the button. That's dismiss the whole settings stack & show user the `Home`. How to achieve it?

```js
const SettingsTwoScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   ...
   return (
      ...
      <Button onPress={/*dismiss the settings stack*/}/>
   )
}
```

(Of course I can't use the `navigation.goBack()` which only navigate user back to the previous screen i.e. `SettingOneScreen` in this case.)

Comment: Can you throw a snack demo with repo & expected result I will solve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 1-) use navigate.

```js
//this will go back to Home and remove any screens after that. 
navigation.navigate('Home')
```

[docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigate) say that.

> In a stack navigator, calling navigate with a screen name will result in different behavior based on if the screen is already present or not. If the screen is already present in the stack's history, `it'll go back to that screen and remove any screens after that`. If the screen is not present, it'll push a new screen.

### 2-) use reset.

```js
navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
})}
```

see [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#reset) about reset

### 3-) use replace then goBack.

```js
//from SettingsOne call replace instead navigate
//this will remove SettingsOne and push SettingsTwo
navigation.replace('SettingsTwo');


//then from SettingsTwo 
//calling goBack will back to home because SettingsOne removed in last step 
navigation.goBack();
```

### 4-) use one stack with pop.

```js
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

//merge two stacks in one
<NavigationContainer>
   <rootStack.Navigator>
     <rootStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
     <rootStack.Screen name="SettingsOne" component={SettingsOneScreen} />
     <rootStack.Screen name="SettingsTwo" component={SettingsTwoScreen} />
   </rootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

//back 2 screen
navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(2));
```

see [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#pop) about pop

for methods 1, 2 you can try snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/navigation-bact-to).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem before, this will help you more

```
<Button onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Settings",{
    screen: 'SettingsTwo',
    params: { data: data }//put here the data that you want to send to SettingTow
 )}
 />
 

//more explanation
goto = (data) => {
navigation.navigate('parent_stack', {
    screen: 'screen_on_children_stack',
    params: { data: data }
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get why I would pass data to `SettingsTwoScreen`? My question is about from SettingsTwoScreen go back to Home screen, I hope I could achieve that by somehow dismiss the Settings stack. I understand your answer for that but don't understand why passing data? It would be nice if you could explain the `data` part for my case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Switch navigator for the "root" app and create two stacks "home" and "setting".

```
const Root = ()=> (createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
     
      Home: Home,
      Settings: Settings,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  )

// The Settings screen is a nested stack navigator
const Settings = ()=> {
  const settingsStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <settingsStack.Navigator>
      <settingsStack.Screen name="SettingsOne" component={SettingsOneScreen} />
      <settingsStack.Screen name="SettingsTwo" component={SettingsTwoScreen} />
    </settingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then you can easily switch between stacks of Home and Settings

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings');
```

Comment: Don't use switch on react-navigation v5

Comment: Is there any specific reason of not using it @RajendranNadar

Comment: Because we can use a simple ternary operator or if else condition to switch and it is not recommended. It was removed from core in RN v5.

Answer (score -1):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#dismiss

```
 navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().pop();
```